# Duration of adiabatic expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

I have a problem in which an adiabatic expansion occurs in a vertical piston and ideal gas system.

There is a piston that is being held down, and then when it is released, the gas expands in such way that it shoots the piston out of the system.

I'm wondering how I can calculate the time it takes from the moment in which the piston is released until it shoots out of the system.
I already calculated the net work performed, the speed of the piston when it exits the system and the initial and final values for temperature, pressure and volume

I'd really appreciate your help

Comment: Did. you assume a reversible expansion of the gas?

Comment: The process is irreversible